# Find the image of the half plane $y>1$ under the transformation $w = (1 - i) z$

Tags: complex-analysis, linear-transformations

This is what I have so far:

Write $Z = (1 - i)z$,

$z = r e^{(i\theta)}$.

$ 1 - i = \sqrt2e^{(3\pi/4)i}$

$ Z = (\sqrt2r)e^{i(\theta+3\pi/4)}$

Hence it expands the radius vector for a nonzero point z by the factor $\sqrt2$ and rotates it counterclockwise $3\pi/4$ radians about the origin.

But I am not sure what the graph looks like after the shifts/expansions.

Comment: No, $1-i= \sqrt 2 e^{-i\pi/4}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click [HERE](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ujhnwdbfb3) to see a graph of what's going on.

Comment: Like my comment god damnit lol

Answer (score 1):

The complex number $1-i$ is not equal to $\sqrt{2}e^{i\big(\frac{3\pi}{4}\big)}.$

You may find it easier to write $Z$ as $(x+y)+i(-x+y)$ and then look at the image of a horizontal line $y=a$ for $a\geq1.$